# Text-overflow on a div containing php echo?

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck on how to use the 'text-overflow' function.

Heres my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#filenm {   white-space: nowrap;    width: 100%;    overflow: hidden;   text-overflow: ellipsis; } </style>

<td width="614" height="28" colspan="18" background="images/site_23.gif"><div id="filenm" style="display:block; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; text-align:center;"> <?php $filename = $_GET['filename']; echo 'File Name:'.$filename.'.zip'; ?></div></td>
```

Id like the text in the div 'filenm' to not over-flow out of the box that it is in.

Huge thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Can you post more of your source code? it's hard to make out other factors with just the incomplete code snippet.

Comment: negative.. the issue is as plain as a cracker with no cheese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a height for overflow for it to work:

```
    #filenm{
      height: 300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this example you hide the text if its not fit in the div and replace the text that not fit in to dots. You can see a working version on http://jsfiddle.net/McXav/8/

#### HTML

```
<div> This text is way to long for this div</div>
```

#### CSS

```
  div {
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      overflow:hidden;
      white-space:nowrap;
      width: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

#### Output

> This text is w...